# What exactly is the effect of Terminalia Arjuna in Hepatic Lipid Peroxidation?

Tags: metabolism, liver, herbs

[This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S222541101630236X) artice says that Terminalia Arjuna (TA) increases hepatic [lipid peroxidation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/lipid-peroxidation) (LPO)

> administration of arjuna resulted in reduction of thyroid hormone concentration in euthyroid animals, whereas the hepatic LPO was increased. Thus, high amounts of the plant extract should not be consumed, as it may induce hepatotoxicity

---

But then, [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11010-006-0433-8) article says the opposite

> This protective effect of EETA was associated with inhibition of LPO induced by DEN and to maintain the antioxidant enzyme levels. Our results show an antioxidant activity of T. arjuna bark against DEN-induced liver cancer.

So what exactly is the effect of TA on LPO? Does it increase or decrease hepatic LPO?

---

Edit: I found this really interesting and weird. In the first article, which references to [Parmar et al](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17020158/), which says that TA increases hepatic LPO, the paper has this data.

[image]

Now if you observe, T4 treatment increases hepatic LPO, but when given in combination with TA, TA corrects the increased hepatic LPO and normalises it, but when TA is given alone it increases heaptic LPO?? This is quite odd.

Comment: I edited your question to define acronyms as required in https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/972/7951 can you please help with the rest of the acronyms? And what is *Paramar et al*?

Comment: @ChrisRogers thank you